# make two threads process independent without sleep/wait/notify

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

i am running two threads one of the thread is to read Feed and the get the elements into global variables and other thread is used to get the info from the global variables and it will start downloading the files.

the processing time of ***writefile*** thread is taking just milliSeconds and the processing time of ***download*** thread may take upto more than 40secs because it depends upon the file.

Problem :

***writefile*** thread has to run every 4secs because i dont to have miss the Feed which is giving info every seconds but if i run the below program the ***writefile*** thread is not at all executing until the ***download*** threads complete its process.

solution required:

even ***download*** threads processing time is more than  1 minute by that time i should call ***writefile*** 15 times (15*4secs) .
(wait or sleep methods will delay my process because Feed is giving me thousands of Files in just few hours)

please go through the below code. please edit and share the Knowledge.

thanks in advance

```
  public class Upload {
    static List<DTOs> list = new ArrayList<E>();
    String date = "";
    Map<String, DTO> map = new HashMap<String, DTO>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            Thread writefile = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    write();
                    // map collection is being used in download thread and also
                    // list
                }
            };

            Thread download = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    downloadProcess(list, date);
                }
            };

            writefile.start();
            download.start();

            try {
                writefile.join();
                download.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You collections are not thread safe, your thread only run once and it's not clear why you have more than one thread since as a you say one runs fast and the other spends most of it's time waiting for the network.

Comment: @PeterLawrey one thread is reading the feed and it is fast compared to another thread. i am starting both the thread in while loop.

Comment: I got that, but it doesn't address my point as to why you are doing this or why the collection is not thread safe. hint: it is more complicated but not guaranteed to be any faster.

Comment: my real problem is two threads should work independently, one should not wait for another to execute its process, you are asking about the variables i am using but its not really my concern

Comment: It hard to know what to suggest you do instead as it doesn't appear to make sense in the first place. The threads are running concurrently but without thread safety there is no guarantee when/if one thread will see the updates of the other.

Comment: What feed? If it's a socket and you read it in blocking mode, (a) you will block until data arrives, and (b) if the sender sends faster than you read, it will block. It isn't clear that you have any problem to solve, let alone any need for multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

Several points here.

1. Your code isn't running asynchronously because you join the threads at the end of each loop. This means the main thread has to wait for the others to complete each time through.
2. There's no reason to recreate the threads each time. This is wasted overhead.
3. As pointed out, it doesn't appear you're handling your data structures in a thread safe way.  Not sure why you're passing list in to download, since that's got a global static instance.

You get what you want, I'd do the following:

1. Kick off one thread to do the feed monitoring. Have it loop inside the thread.
2. Use a thread worker pool for the downloads. No reason not to have more than one download running at a time, but you probably do want to limit the total.
3. Make sure you're locking access to the shared data structures. This should be done so access is very fast, so neither thread blocks for long.

So the overall algorithm is to start one monitor thread, start one work delegation thread that manages a thread pool for downloads, have the monitor thread receive a new file or set of files to download. Lock your shared data only long enough to update the pending list. Have the download manager thread lock only long enough to pull the next job when a worker is available.